# Probability Discrete Math Bag

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A bag contains 15 different objects, 5 red object, 5 blue objects, and 5 white objects. If 3 objects are chosen at random

a) What is the probability that 3 objects of the same color are chosen?

b) What is the probability that 3 objects, one of each color are chosen?

For a the answer that I was given is 3$\lgroup\frac{5\choose3}{15\choose3}\rgroup$
But that doesn't make sense.  Another way was 15(2)(1)/$15\choose3$  but yet again it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do you say that $3\left(\frac{5\choose 3}{15\choose 3}\right)$ doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 0):

For part a), examine the situation where you want to pick, say, exactly 3 red objects.

There are ${5\choose3}$ ways that you can pick 3 red objects. There are ${15\choose3}$ ways to pick any object at all. So you take the number of desired outcomes and divide by the number of all possible outcomes. This gives you $\frac{5\choose3}{15\choose3}$.

But the goal isn't to get 3 red objects, it's to get 3 of the same colour. Since there are 3 colours you triple the number of desired outcomes. This gives you $3\lgroup\frac{5\choose3}{15\choose3}\rgroup$.

For $\frac{15(2)(1)}{15\choose3}$. The bottom term of $15\choose3$ follows the same logic as the above answer (all possible ways to choose the objects).

For the numerator you need to pick an object. There are 15. Now your desired colour is locked in. You pick another object, of which there are 4 remaining that you want. Then another when 3 remain. This gives $(15)(4)(3)$. But the order doesn't matter, and there are $3!$ ways to arrange them. So that gives $\frac{(15)(4)(3)}{3!}$. If you eliminate the $3!$  by cancelling out a 3, then a 2, you get $(15)(2)(1)$.

For the sake of interest, here's a different way to solve the problem.

You're picking 3 objects. You pick your first object. It doesn't matter what it is. This just happens. This is now your desired object colour. You now have 4 desired objects out of 14 possible objects to choose from, which is a $\frac{4}{14}$ chance.

Then you have 3 desired objects out of 13, or a $\frac{3}{13}$ chance.

This results in $(\frac{4}{14})(\frac{3}{13}) = \frac{12}{182} = \frac{6}{91}$, which matches the answer above.

You posted a b) part but didn't make any specific mention of it. Is there something with b) that needs clarification?